# How to filter out special character in javascript

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this javascript (JSFiddle below):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("id"), this.checked)
  var choosedString = "";
  if ($('#A').prop('checked')) {
    choosedString = "A"
  }
  if ($('#Aplus').prop('checked')) {
  choosedString += choosedString.length > 0 ? "|" : "";
  choosedString += "A\\+"
  }

console.log(table)
table.column(3).search(choosedString,  true, false).draw();

  });

});
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/10uhwapv/93/)

I need to select 'A' and/or 'A+' values from the table via the 2 checkboxes. I figured out how to select 'A+', but when I'm trying to choose 'A', also the A+ are included in the selection. How to filter out the special character? Thank you.

Comment: I’d say this is less of a general JS question, and more one about the specifics of how DataTable’s search method works. Have you checked the documentation for that already, whether it allows for a “strict” search mode in some way?

Comment: CBroe, I added the tag. I tried to find it in documentation, but there is nothing similar.

Comment: @culter You could use filters for example, to filter the dataset through an own callback function. https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()

Comment: Try to escape the slash as well `A\\\\+`

Comment: Titus, this did'nt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the regular expression mode of the `search` method here already - but the problem with that is, that `A` as a “regular expression” of course still matches anything that contains an `A` *anywhere*, and doesn’t limit it any further.

If you *anchor* these expressions at the start and end using `^` and `$`, you should be able to get what you want:

```
if ($('#A').prop('checked')) {
  choosedString = "^A$"
}
if ($('#Aplus').prop('checked')) {
  choosedString += choosedString.length > 0 ? "|" : "";
  choosedString += "^A\\+$"
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/10uhwapv/102/

Comment: Thanks, CBroe. It's working fine and you was 1 minute quicker than the others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^` and `$` anchors to match the start and end of the string:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"), this.checked)
    var choosedString = "";
    if ($('#A').prop('checked')) {
      choosedString = "^A$"; // Modified here
    }
    if ($('#Aplus').prop('checked')) {
      choosedString += choosedString.length > 0 ? "|" : "";
      choosedString += "A\\+"
    }
    console.log(table)
    table.column(3).search(choosedString,  true, false).draw();

  });

});
```

Working fiddle (using only `$`): https://jsfiddle.net/10uhwapv/96/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this line

```
table.column(3).search(choosedString,  true, false).draw();
```

to

```
table.column(3).search("^" + choosedString + "$", true, false).draw();
```

then you can filter table by exact match A OR A+.You can see demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/10uhwapv/123/)

Comment: But the difference is, that when I deselect both checkboxes, no data is displayed.

Comment: i update js fiddle as per your requirement.so now you can see latest code,that solve your issue.